# while reusing html component is it possible to make css and bootstrap(cdns) of that to that component and don't let it disturb the other page;

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am reusing the HTML component by

```js
$.get("nav.html", function(data) {
  $("#fulloptions").replaceWith(data)
})
```

However, `nav.html` uses another Bootstrap version and my index file uses another so it is disturbing both.

Is there a way to limit Bootstrap CDN in `nav.html` to itself and they don't cause trouble in `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using templating and using partials i.e. reusing the components like head tag in other files, it automatically takes all the attributes of the head tag and applies it to body. In short it appends your code in one file, in the sequence of your usage.
so once you apply one CDN in head, it gets applied to all other elements